# How to enhance D3.js 'smooth scrolling' demo?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition, tween

js people,

I am looking at this demo:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1649463

It shows a 'smooth scrolling' technique which scrolls to the end of the page.

How do I enhance it so it scrolls to an id or selection?

I want to create a function called **slowscroll**().

I want the API call to look something like this:

```
d3.select('#mybutton')
  .on('click',function(){
    slowscroll(mydelay, myduration, '#stophere');});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to stop on a button click and resume from there on.

```
//add listener to stop
d3.select("#stop").on("click", function () {
    //stop the transition
    d3.select("body").transition().duration(0);
});
//add listeners to resume
d3.select("#resume").on("click", function () {
    //resume the transition
    d3.select("body").transition()
    .delay(1)
    .duration(7500)
    .tween("scroll", scrollTween(document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height - window.innerHeight));
});
```

Full working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/xyczrts2/1/).

Answer (score 0):

instead of going all the way to the end you can calculate the offset as

```
var offset = $(selector).offset().top - window.scrollY;
```

and then use it in a function

```
function scrollToElem(delay, duration, selector){
var offset = $(selector).offset().top - window.scrollY;

d3.transition()
    .delay(1500)
    .duration(7500)
    .tween("scroll", scrollTween(offset));

}
```

event binding

```
d3.select('#my-button')
.on('click',function(){
scrollToElem(1500, 7500, '#target');});
```

here's full code 
https://jsfiddle.net/mddm8xxt/2/

Comment: it is actually not a universal solution, see what happens in https://jsfiddle.net/mddm8xxt/3/ whan you scroll a bit before hiting the button